# Storing values in different variables in nested for loop

Tags: python, excel, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm currently writing a piece of code that loops through the rows and columns of a spreadsheet and then uses the value of the cell at row `r` and column `c` in the parameter of a function. I currently have it working as following:

```
for i in range (1, ws.max_row+1): 
    first_column = worksheet.cell(i,1).value
    second_column = worksheet.cell(i,2).value
    third_column = worksheet.cell(i,3).value
    result = functionX.create(first_column, second_column, third_column)
```

Where the index `i` loops through the rows in the sheet. I'm using the `worksheet.cell(row,column).value` function from the `openpyxl` library and store them in the `x_column` variables. Later, these variables get used as parameters in the `class.create()` function **within the same for loop**.

However, what I would like to do is to keep track of the columns in the loop as well, with a separate index. Reason for this is that I would like to print out a message to the user when he an empty cell has been encountered at row `i` and column `j`.

As a solution, I thought it could be useful to use a nested for loop to keep track of the columns:

```
for i in range (1, ws.max_row+1):
    for j in range (1,4):
        first_column = worksheet.cell(i,j).value
        second_column = worksheet.cell(i,j).value
        third_column = worksheet.cell(i,j).value
    result = functionX.create(first_column, second_column, third_column)
```

However, this will obviously not increment the index `j` within the same iteration of the second loop. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Please format your code. Python is very sensitive to indenting, as are python programmers.

Comment: @quamrana Done! :)

Comment: @Graipher was just an abstraction, but edited either way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use a for loop for the columns, you could use a list to gatter the values of the cells and then unpack that list to pass the gattered values to the method `.create()`.

This is also flexible if you want to add more columns without changing a lot of code, just increase the range of the second loop.

It could look like this:

```
for i in range (1, ws.max_row+1):
    column_list = []
    for j in range (1, 4):
        column_list.append(worksheet.cell(i,j).value)

    # the '*' unpacks the whole list
    result = the_class.create(*column_list)
```

Does that work for you?